# Adding a phpbb forum under laravel app

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, phpbb3

I'm trying to include a brand new phpbb 3.1 forum to my laravel 5.0 website... but I can't find the best way to do that.
Is it possible to copy the phpbb folder in the laravel structure and add a route to it?

Thanks a lot

K.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a subdomain to host the phpBB forum. I guess it's better than trying to modify phpBB code to make it work under laravel structure.